# How to use powershell background jobs to delete a SPListItem in SharePoint 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to delete items from a document library using powershell 2.0, but not all of them, only ones that pass some of my if statements (and no I can't use CAML for all my conditions). So I have to loop through the items and then delete it. Except it takes so long to delete all the items. So I want to use background jobs. I have this code:

```
$spListItem = .....; # I get the item here
$task = {
    PARAM($spListItem);
    $spListItem.Delete();
}
$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $task -ArgumentList $spListItem;
```

but this code is not working. Does anyone know what is wrong?

ERROR:

```
Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem] doesn't contain a method named 'Delete'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Delete:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Please be more elaborate than "is not working", we'll need more details to help you figure this out

Comment: ok i put the error message